# Legendre transform of multivariable function.

Tags: convex-analysis, classical-mechanics

This is a problem from my lecture on analytical mechanics:

1) Consider a function $U$ of two variables $$U = U(S,V) \quad \text{with } \quad  dU = TdS-PdV.$$
Construct the Legendre transform of $U$ which uses $T$ as independent variable and calculate its derivative with respect to $T$ and $V$.

I find this problem very confusing for 2 reasons:

- I was under the impression that we could only calculate the Legendre transform of a real valued convex function of one variable;
- $T$ is not a variable of $U$ so why does the problem state that $T$ is and independent variable of $U$ ?

Could someone clarify what I'm supposed to be doing in this exercise ?

Comment: You can only not use $T$ as independent variable if $T$ is constant or non-monotonous along the solution curves of the given direction field.

Comment: What does it mean to use $T$ as a variable when $U$ is note a function of $T$ ?

Comment: You have a curve. You have a function on the curve that is locally monotonous. You can use via implicit function theorem that function locally as parameter of the curve.